# Weight painting is acting wierd

Tags: modeling

What does it mean when it looks like this? I'm not sure what I did wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mean not moving with the selected bone?

Comment: Please add more details as to what *specifically* you find wrong with what is in that image.

Comment: I want the finger to look realistic when bending...

Comment: I want all other bones ahead of the first finger bone to look straight when bending the first bone.

Comment: @AidanPallian go through each bone and  do the weight painting  ,the mesh will follow automatically

Comment: i painted each bone already and it does this

Comment: Look back at the question i posted some images showing what i did wrong

Comment: @RayMairlot Its creasing all over the finger when im trying to make it straight. the creases get worse and worse as i bend it farther and farther. I need to fix it.

Comment: @AidanPallian what about the third bone ? try selecting the other finger bones may be you painted by mistake ? if you can upload the blend file at least this part it would be easier

Comment: ill upload it :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ZiQtohl3tmRnRzRGtXbE53ajA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

A vertex can be in multiple vertex groups. I think that's why you groups look good but move like that : other associated vertex groups. You can see that in edit mode with the selected vertices in N panel, vertex weight with associated groups.

[image]

Here you can change weight or remove a group from the list of vertices associated groups

Comment: more than a tip, an answer. Your fingers are close to each other, automatic weights usually give weird results on fingers.

Answer (score 1):

The finger mesh is parented to more than one bone "precisely the next finger" as you can see, and the last bone of the finger has no vertices:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The main problem is the **normals** of the mesh, so to solve the problem :

- delete the **Armature modifier**
- select the body and go in edit mode select all vertices and **Recalculate the normals**
- go to object mode and parent the body to the Armature using **Automatic weight**

this will give you a clean result like this :

[image]

Comment: @AidanPallian in the file you upload you have applied the subsurf modifier, it will give a better result if you keep it under the armature modifier